# Push notification in flutter with IO socket and nodejs

Tags: node.js, flutter, dart, socket.io, push-notification

I have created an app in Flutter with backend in node js and MongoDB hosted on my AWS server. For chat and notification, I am using io socket. I want to implement push notification.

I want to receive push notification just like WhatsApp and Gmail even after force closing them?

 I know there is FCM(firebase cloud messaging) for push notification, But can This be done without it, as I am doing everything without implementing firebase and using IO socket and my own database.
How can this be achieved, using IO sockets in a flutter? or is it like it has to be done using FCM only?

Comment: Hi, I have the same case like yours. Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Use SocketIO for remote push notifications is bad idea. Probably it is possible to achieve this with background processing, but definitely it is much more complicated way to develop and to use.

Using Firebase is a good practice for Flutter, it is easy to configure. Besides, it is an official way to make push notifications for android. My advice is to use FCM - here is [official docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview/).